# Regex in Python to get text after ":"

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I've been trying different combinations to extract the text after ":".

```py
    materials[3] = 'PE HD Monofilament Yarn CFR India Assessment Main Ports Spot 2-4 Weeks Full Market Range Weekly (Low) : USD/tonne'

    re.match(r'(?<=:+.)(.*)', materials[3])
```

But I've trying different errors on PyCharm, although the sequence aobe was ok when I tested in https://regexr.com/ and simulated the reading.

The error retrieved from Python is the following:

```py
  re.match(r'(?<=:+.)(.*)', materials[3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\p119124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-210-556fd124536f>", line 1, in <module>
    re.match(r'(?<=:+.)(.*)', materials[3])
  File "C:\Users\p119124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 173, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "C:\Users\p119124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\p119124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\sre_compile.py", line 768, in compile
    code = _code(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\p119124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\sre_compile.py", line 607, in _code
    _compile(code, p.data, flags)
  File "C:\Users\p119124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\sre_compile.py", line 182, in _compile
    raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Could you help me out?

The idea is just to extract the "**USD/tonne**".

Comment: Your re might be ok, but you should read the documentation for `re.match()` see https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=match#re.match

Answer (score 3):

Lookbehind patterns in `re` must match a fixed length string.

Use a capturing group:

```py
import re
materials = 'PE HD Monofilament Yarn CFR India Assessment Main Ports Spot 2-4 Weeks Full Market Range Weekly (Low) : USD/tonne'
match = re.search(r'.*:\s*(.+)', materials)
if match:
  print(match.group(1))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##PY5La8JAFIX3@RVnlxlbU/pYBboQH1ioIIpIoZtBr2Zwcme4d0T89THNosvz4Hwn3XMT@b3rfJuiZAgVrcsk3gXFJ8r1HMsZVpHjyQfXEmf8OGFMFxt88dE7TFRJdUhWzjPW/Yxim2LG2/gDe6KLYnENoY/lQhkbx2ca/HCH@Y43ixq77ewlR2Yq//iHpmcLVUpODo2RshrVvzoy1ZMtn/F/0Bb@hKFeF0ASz9kMsjpLvCbzam3XPQA) and a [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/RTGByd/1).

**Expression explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to use a regex for this at all. `str.split` will work fine for such a straightforward use case.

```
materials[3].split(':')[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
print(re.search(r'(\s+?:\s+)(.*)', materials).group(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a lookbehind. A very simple solution would be this:

```
import re
materials = 'PE HD Monofilament Yarn CFR India Assessment Main Ports Spot 2-4 Weeks Full Market Range Weekly (Low) : USD/tonne'
output = re.search(":.*", materials)
print(output.group(0)[2:])
#output: 'USD/tonne'
```

Or this, if you don't want to slice the string and get it purely with the regex:

```
output = re.search("(?:: )(.*)", materials)
print(output.group(1))
#output: USD/tonne
```